# stop div animating past container edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been dabling with a javascript image panner to which I have hacked and shredded together from code on here... I have now abandoned this for a simpler method but need advice on how to do a couple of things.

I have this code for left and right buttons.

```
<div id="wrap">

<div class="entrance-hall pan-image">


</div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Move Left" class="nav-left" onclick="pan_animate('-=20%')"  />
<input type="button" value="Move Right" class="nav-right"  onclick="pan_animate('+=20%')" />
```

and this for the javascript.

```
function pan_animate(px) {
$('.pan-image').animate({
    'marginLeft' : px
});
}
```

It pans an image left or right 20% within the wrapping div however I want to...

1. make it scroll smoothly rather than in increments of a percentage
2. stop going past the edge of the left and right container
3. start at the center of the image.

Not asking for much eh? Hope this makes sense and someone can help!

Cheers.

css added

```
#wrap {
margin-bottom:60px;
border:4px solid white;
overflow:hidden;
}


 .pan-image {
position:relative;
width:2106px; 
height:395px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-1053px;
 }

 /* -- ===entrance hall=== -- */

.entrance-hall { 
background:url(/staging/kennawayhouse.org.uk/images/1-entrance-hall.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make it scroll smoothly rather than in increments of a percentage

One way to achieve this is simply using `easing` functions. From the jQuery animate api:

> Easing
>
> The remaining parameter of .animate() is a string naming an easing function to use. An easing function specifies the speed at which the animation progresses at different points within the animation. The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins, most notably the jQuery UI suite.

Your code could be then, changed to:

```
function pan_animate(px) {
    $('.pan-image').animate({'marginLeft' : px}, 'linear'); // Swing and Linear comes in jQuery, but swing is the default value.
}
```

And **some** smooth will be perceived.

- Stop going past the edge of the left and right container

This one will need some `css` hack, but `position:absolute;left:5x;top:5px` **may** solve your problem about the inner element. If you want an answer more accurate than **may**, you can post your css code.

**EDIT**

Based on your css code, I've achieved a function that alert if your margin has trespassed the limit of it's parent when moving:

```
function pan_animate(px) {
    
    $marginLeftCss = $(".pan-image").css("marginLeft").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
    $n = px.replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
    $x = (px.indexOf("-")==0) ? 1 - ($n/100):($n/100);
    
    $marginLeft = $marginLeftCss * $x;
    
    $width = $(".pan-image").width();
    $width += $(".pan-image").parent().width();
    
    if($marginLeft > - $width && $marginLeft < $width) //4212 = width*2
        $('.pan-image').animate({'marginLeft' : px}, 'linear');
    else
        alert("pan image reached it\'s end "  + $marginLeft);
}
```

You can check it a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brunovieira/3wHn3/7/

- Start at the center of the image.

In order to center your `$(".pan-image")` elements you can use two approaches, the css one: `position:relative;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto`, or, in case position relative is not an option, you can center your element using jQuery **like**:

```
$parentHeight = $(".pan-image").parent().height();
$parentWidth = $(".pan-image").parent().width();

$panImageHeight = $(".pan-image").height();
$panImageWidth = $(".pan-image").width();

$(".pan-image").css('position','absolute','top',($parentHeight - $panImageHeight)/2 + 'px', 'left',($parentWidth - $panImageWidth)/2+'px');
```

Again, depending of your coding, the conditions above answered may not work.

Comment: Ok, I just added your code but it didn't work it seemed to break it so I gusse I'm doing something wrong... I've added the css and the class in the HTML for the background image. @Bruno

Comment: Ah yes I missed that too! OK, it's working now but I think I may now be thinking I've got my question a little wrong. I'm thinking that if you hold the button it will scroll until release but this will be OK for now definitely!! Also I solved the centering with this css above on the .pan-image

Comment: I can't stop it going past the ends though... @Bruno

Comment: Doing so, everytime you resize, your div will be out of center. This is a better way: position:relative;
width:2106px; 
height:395px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto; Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brunovieira/3wHn3/2/

Comment: Working on the stoping of animation, give me a minut

Comment: Ah cool, a JSFIDDLE. Um, the margin left right auto doesn't seem to work for some reason I'll persist with it, though taking the width out means it loops continuously which could be cool, but I'll see what you come with as I'm sure it will be better. Is there a way of having it so if the button is held down it will scroll until release. This could throw up device issues though... Cheers so much for this! @Bruno

Comment: This new EDITION alerts when your pan-image trespassed your limits. It's up to you now to modify the code to suit your needs. Cheers

Comment: If an answer is correct, please mark as so, otherwise stackoverflow won't ever know that your problem has been solved. Consider up vote answers that were somewhat useful. This helps other users with similar questions to find answers more easily